# Windows DB2 9.7 FP8 - The request failed because private virtual memory could not be allocated. SQLSTATE=57011

Tags: ibm, db2

I have a Windows DB2 9.7 FP8 server running on Windows 2003 x86 that for some reason every time I launch Center Administrator or the CLI and try to connect to a database, I get the error "[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1219N The request failed because private virtual memory could not be allocated.  SQLSTATE=57011".

Explanation:

The instance was unable to allocate enough private virtual memory to process the request.  This may be a result of shared memory allocations made in other (unrelated) processes.

User response:

The problem may be corrected by:
* Stopping other applications running on the machine, especially those that use large amounts of shared memory.

sqlcode: -1219

sqlstate: 57011

I have the same programs I've always had loaded on this server.  I'm not sure when exactly the issue started, since I don't need to access the databases too often directly on server.  I can launch Center Administrator from another server and connect remotely just fine.

I have over 1GB free memory.

I even rebooted server and changed boot.ini to include /3GB switch to give more memory (3GB instead of 2GB) to user processes.

I tried stopped a bunch of unused servers.

In short, I have no idea why this error is happening and if I can't resolve soon, will have to resort to upgrading to another FP or v10.  I'm not sure uninstalling and reinstalling will work since I have active databases on the server?

Note: I'm not a DB2 expert and have to use it because SQL Server is too expensive and company has migrated off this platform.  Go figure.  Yet, everything I do with DB2 seems to be like hitting a break wall.

Any help would be appreciated.

Output from "db2 get dbm cfg" produced the following:

```
          Database Manager Configuration
     Node type = Database Server with local and remote clients
Database manager configuration release level            = 0x0d00
CPU speed (millisec/instruction)             (CPUSPEED) = 1.259585e-007
Max number of concurrently active databases     (NUMDB) = 128
Federated Database System Support           (FEDERATED) = NO
Transaction processor monitor name        (TP_MON_NAME) = 
Default charge-back account           (DFT_ACCOUNT_STR) = 
Java Development Kit installation path       (JDK_PATH) = C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\jdk
Diagnostic error capture level              (DIAGLEVEL) = 3
Notify Level                              (NOTIFYLEVEL) = 3
Diagnostic data directory path               (DIAGPATH) = 
 Alternate diagnostic data directory path (ALT_DIAGPATH) = 
 Size of rotating db2diag & notify logs (MB)  (DIAGSIZE) = 0

Default database monitor switches
   Buffer pool                         (DFT_MON_BUFPOOL) = OFF
   Lock                                   (DFT_MON_LOCK) = OFF
   Sort                                   (DFT_MON_SORT) = OFF
   Statement                              (DFT_MON_STMT) = OFF
   Table                                 (DFT_MON_TABLE) = OFF
   Timestamp                         (DFT_MON_TIMESTAMP) = ON
   Unit of work                            (DFT_MON_UOW) = OFF
Monitor health of instance and databases   (HEALTH_MON) = ON

SYSADM group name                        (SYSADM_GROUP) = 
 SYSCTRL group name                      (SYSCTRL_GROUP) = 
 SYSMAINT group name                    (SYSMAINT_GROUP) = 
 SYSMON group name                        (SYSMON_GROUP) = 

Client Userid-Password Plugin          (CLNT_PW_PLUGIN) = 
 Client Kerberos Plugin                (CLNT_KRB_PLUGIN) = IBMkrb5
Group Plugin                             (GROUP_PLUGIN) = 
 GSS Plugin for Local Authorization    (LOCAL_GSSPLUGIN) = 
 Server Plugin Mode                    (SRV_PLUGIN_MODE) = UNFENCED
Server List of GSS Plugins      (SRVCON_GSSPLUGIN_LIST) = 
 Server Userid-Password Plugin        (SRVCON_PW_PLUGIN) = 
 Server Connection Authentication          (SRVCON_AUTH) = NOT_SPECIFIED
Cluster manager                           (CLUSTER_MGR) = 

Database manager authentication        (AUTHENTICATION) = SERVER
Alternate authentication           (ALTERNATE_AUTH_ENC) = NOT_SPECIFIED
Cataloging allowed without authority   (CATALOG_NOAUTH) = NO
Trust all clients                      (TRUST_ALLCLNTS) = YES
Trusted client authentication          (TRUST_CLNTAUTH) = CLIENT

Bypass federated authentication            (FED_NOAUTH) = NO
Default database path                       (DFTDBPATH) = C:
Database monitor heap size (4KB)          (MON_HEAP_SZ) = AUTOMATIC(66)
Java Virtual Machine heap size (4KB)     (JAVA_HEAP_SZ) = 2048
Audit buffer size (4KB)                  (AUDIT_BUF_SZ) = 0
Size of instance shared memory (4KB)  (INSTANCE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(838861)
Agent stack size                       (AGENT_STACK_SZ) = 64
Sort heap threshold (4KB)                  (SHEAPTHRES) = 0
Directory cache support                     (DIR_CACHE) = YES
Application support layer heap size (4KB)   (ASLHEAPSZ) = 15
Max requester I/O block size (bytes)         (RQRIOBLK) = 32767

Workload impact by throttled utilities(UTIL_IMPACT_LIM) = 10

Priority of agents                           (AGENTPRI) = SYSTEM
Agent pool size                        (NUM_POOLAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(100)
Initial number of agents in pool       (NUM_INITAGENTS) = 0
Max number of coordinating agents     (MAX_COORDAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(200)
Max number of client connections      (MAX_CONNECTIONS) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)
Keep fenced process                        (KEEPFENCED) = YES
Number of pooled fenced processes         (FENCED_POOL) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)
Initial number of fenced processes     (NUM_INITFENCED) = 0
Index re-creation time and redo index build  (INDEXREC) = RESTART
Transaction manager database name         (TM_DATABASE) = 1ST_CONN
Transaction resync interval (sec)     (RESYNC_INTERVAL) = 180
SPM name                                     (SPM_NAME) = DSMINDB2
SPM log size                          (SPM_LOG_FILE_SZ) = 256
SPM resync agent limit                 (SPM_MAX_RESYNC) = 20
SPM log path                             (SPM_LOG_PATH) = 
TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = db2c_DB2
Discovery mode                               (DISCOVER) = SEARCH
Discover server instance                (DISCOVER_INST) = ENABLE
SSL server keydb file                   (SSL_SVR_KEYDB) = 
 SSL server stash file                   (SSL_SVR_STASH) = 
 SSL server certificate label            (SSL_SVR_LABEL) = 
 SSL service name                         (SSL_SVCENAME) = 
 SSL cipher specs                      (SSL_CIPHERSPECS) = 
 SSL versions                             (SSL_VERSIONS) = 
 SSL client keydb file                  (SSL_CLNT_KEYDB) = 
 SSL client stash file                  (SSL_CLNT_STASH) = 
Maximum query degree of parallelism   (MAX_QUERYDEGREE) = ANY
Enable intra-partition parallelism     (INTRA_PARALLEL) = NO

No. of int. communication buffers(4KB)(FCM_NUM_BUFFERS) = AUTOMATIC(1024)
No. of int. communication channels   (FCM_NUM_CHANNELS) = AUTOMATIC(512)
db2start/db2stop timeout (min)        (START_STOP_TIME) = 10
```

Output from "db2 get db cfg for mydatabasename produced the following:

```
SQL1219N  The request failed because private virtual memory could not be allocated.  SQLSTATE=57011
```

** Note that all my databases on this server seem to have the same issue.  I'm not sure if this started after a 9.7 FP8 upgrade or what.

Comment: "I have over 1GB free memory." Yes, but that's free *physical* memory. As the message says, the problem is a shortage of *virtual* memory. You can have plenty of money in your bank account but still be unable to write any checks. How big is your paging file? (A paging file is like a line of credit. It doesn't give you any more money in the bank, but it does let you write more checks.)

Comment: The page file is set to automatic (system managed)

Comment: For the heck of it, I changed it to a min of 2048 and max of 6000GB, rebooted, and still get the same error message.   This is a Windows 2003 R2 x86 system.   Task Manager says 2GB free memory and page file taking 1.5GB of space.   Sounds like in this case I have plenty of money in the bank and plenty of checks to write against it....

Comment: It does. This may be a configuration problem or memory leak in a driver.